# Arduino Bluetooth data (large data files) transfer efficiency using HC05 module

Tags: arduino-mega, bluetooth, hc-05

Im using an HC-05 Bluetooth module connected to my Arduino MEGA. The Arduino has an SD card with some data files stored (sensor readings). After the sensor readings are done, the Arduino then connects to Android phone via Bluetooth and transfers the file data.
This is working fine. Arduino sends the data to HC-05 over Serial port, which transfers it over the air to my Android phone.

But its kinda slow and I hence had a question.

QUESTION: Does the HC-05 buffer the data coming from the Arduino Serial and then send efficiently filled packets over the air. I would like to make sure that the HC-05 isn't inefficiently sending just a single byte or so per Bluetooth packet.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add some performance measurement. What is "kinda slow"? Also add snippet of your sketch showing the serial baudrate and interaction.

Comment: Please upload your code, I will look into it.

Comment: What baud rate is the HC05 using? This will be the limiting factor. It can be changed up to 460800 baud (according to a random datasheet I googled).